# Unable to resolve service for when accessing Serilog ILogger in IResourceAttribute, ExceptionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, attributes, serilog

Implementing a new .NET 6 Web API, I have added SeriLog hoping to handle exceptions through a custom ExceptionFilterAttribute and general HTTPContext entry/exit event logging but I am getting an error when the API is called.

I added Serilog via `Program.cs` like so:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

Logging via ILogger.LogInformation in the controller is fine but when I try and use ILogger from an Attribute or implementation of IResourceAttribute it throws a Dependency Injection exception.

I.e. when I introduce some Attributes that use the ILogger like so to the Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{ 
    options.Filters.Add<MyErrorHandlingAttribute>();
});
```

The Attribute class looks like:

```
    public class MyErrorHandlingAttribute: ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public MyErrorHandlingAttribute(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger= logger?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }
    }
```

Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate
> 'MessageOrchestrator.Common.Attributes.MyErrorHandlingAttribute'.
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method2(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TypeFilterAttribute.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
> serviceProvider)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.DefaultFilterProvider.ProvideFilter(FilterProviderContext
> context, FilterItem filterItem)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.DefaultFilterProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(FilterProviderContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.FilterFactory.CreateUncachedFiltersCore(IFilterProvider[]
> filterProviders, ActionContext actionContext, List`1 filterItems)
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.FilterFactory.GetAllFilters(IFilterProvider[]
> filterProviders, ActionContext actionContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerCache.GetCachedResult(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerRequestDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Sorry am quite new to SeriLog and would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using dependency injection, you need to inject a concrete `ILogger<T>` in your constructor, like e.g. `ILogger<ExceptionFilterAttribute>`.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#create-logs)

> To create logs, use an `ILogger<TCategoryName>` object from dependency injection (DI).

> The ASP.NET Core web apps use `ILogger<T>` to automatically get an `ILogger` instance that uses the fully qualified type name of `T` as the category.

Your code will then look like below.

```
public class MyErrorHandlingAttribute: ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public MyErrorHandlingAttribute(ILogger<ExceptionFilterAttribute> logger)
    {
        _logger= logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }
}
```